# How to set up unit tests in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I cannot run sailsjs unit tests. It seems sails cannot be lifted,
my test (/test/unit/test.js):

```
var Sails = require('sails');
var app;

before(function() {

  console.log('before');

  Sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'error'
    }
  }, function(err, server) {
    console.log('lifted');
    app = server;
    done(err, app);
  });

});

// Global after hook
after(function(done) {
  app.lower(done);
});

describe('mailer service', function() {

  it('should connect to gmail', function() {

    console.log(app);

  });

});
```

In my app folder I run: mocha test/unit/test.js
The "app" variable is undefined, console.log('lifted') is not being triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you try to run all the tests using `mocha` command, is it running?

Comment: @YedhuKrishnan no, it says "0 passing"...

Comment: unit tests should not spin up server or hit databases/do i/o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all.
You need to call before with a done parameter :

```
before(function(done){...})
```

Does your app lift succesfully when you run it with ?

```
sails lift
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I runit with:
../node_modules/.bin/sails lift

Comment: **adding "done" helped**. Many thanks! By the way how can I run all tests typing just "mocha" in my app directory? Is it possible? All my tests are in the "test" directory.

Comment: Hello, I'm glad I was able to help.
To process all tests in one mocha command, you need to create a mocha.opts file in your test folder.
For example, in my last project mine had these options :
--reporter spec
--recursive
--slow 300
--timeout 10000

Comment: could you explain more, do I need to lift my app for every test?